# sonata media change position in gallery

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata-media-bundle

How to implement sortable in Sonata media bundle? I want to change position of images in my gallery. Now I only have =.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to drag the lines to the positions you want?
If you can't drag the lines, maybe there's a problem with your javascript. Check in Firebug console if there's any error.

Hope it helps!